# Tests taking more time than specified timeout using maven surefire

Tags: java, maven, testing, timeout, maven-surefire-plugin

I have all the timeout properties set in my pom.xml.

```
    <plugin>
       <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
       <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
       <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
       <configuration>              
          <forkCount>${surefire.forkNumber}</forkCount>
          <reuseForks>false</reuseForks>
          <argLine>-Xmx2G -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=2G </argLine>
          <parallel>methods</parallel>
          <threadCount>${surefire.threadCount}</threadCount>
          <forkedProcessTimeoutInSeconds>40s</forkedProcessTimeoutInSeconds>
          <forkedProcessExitTimeoutInSeconds>40s</forkedProcessExitTimeoutInSeconds>
          <parallelTestsTimeoutInSeconds>30s</parallelTestsTimeoutInSeconds>
          <parallelTestsTimeoutForcedInSeconds>30s</parallelTestsTimeoutForcedInSeconds> 
       </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

But I still see a few tests are taking more time than 40s (one test is even taking 17 min). What could be the possible reason? How can I enforce 30s timeout with surefire?

Comment: Have you tried writing this configuration without the letter s?
E.g. <forkedProcessTimeoutInSeconds>40</forkedProcessTimeoutInSeconds> etc

Answer (score 0):

Document is specifying that you have to enable option

> parallel

You have to set 
`<parallelTestTimeoutForcedInSeconds>5</parallelTestTimeoutForcedInSeconds>`
to force current running on timeout.

If you are using

> **parallelTestTimeoutInSeconds**
>
> only the queued threads will be stopped from executing

Refer: http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html

Comment: Sorry, I didn't add my entire pom.xml, I am editing to question to add other details. I already have parallel tag in place.

Comment: I have set both the properties?  parallelTestTimeoutForcedInSeconds and parallelTestTimeoutInSeconds

Comment: You didnt provide them in the first post, thats why i have applied them. So what is the result ?

Comment: That is not helping, some tests are still taking more time.